# Tomcat: Additional JARs have been added - context reload

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache-tomee

My development tomee automatically reloads the context when deployment is finished. The log indicates that new Jars have been added but I havent done anything.

Why is the Context reloading?

> sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.federated_search.search_utils.answer.SearchAnswerMessageBodyWriter@1722ba49
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.restServices.MediaProviderJSON@118a5aca
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.restServices.MediaProviderJSONP@64dec4ca
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.ven.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonParseExceptionMapper@5d35cfc8
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.ven.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider@5f47c6d5
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.ven.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider@1c588bfd sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   com.dassault_systemes.platform.ven.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMappingExceptionMapper@eb2f428
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener configureFactory
>   INFO:
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBAccessExceptionMapper@5d3567dc sep
>   03, 2018 8:29:35 FM org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener
>   logEndpoints INFO: REST Application:
>   http://localhost:9311/3dspace/resources/PreCost
>   -> com.matrixone.apps.apr.costing.precost.service.PreCostServiceModular
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener logEndpoints INFO: 
>   Service URI:
>   http://localhost:9311/3dspace/resources/PreCost/PreCostServices
>   -> Pojo com.matrixone.apps.apr.costing.precost.service.PreCostService sep 03, 2018 8:29:35 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener logEndpoints INFO: 
>   GET
>   http://localhost:9311/3dspace/resources/PreCost/PreCostServices/getChartData
>   ->      Response getChartData(HttpServletRequest) throws Exception [2018-09-03 08:29:35,460] Artifact castor-webapp:war exploded:
>   Artifact is deployed successfully [2018-09-03 08:29:35,462] Artifact
>   castor-webapp:war exploded: Deploy took 266 999 milliseconds [TIMING]
>   [pool-8-thread-1] INFO 2018-09-03T08:29:37,266 - The call to
>   [com.hm.pdm.core.common.department.DepartmentLogicImpl.getAll()]
>   returned normally after 5933 ms. - {} [TIMING] [pool-8-thread-1] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:37,267 - The call to
>   [com.hm.pdm.core.common.department.DepartmentLogicImpl.getAll()]
>   returned normally after 5935 ms. - {} sep 03, 2018 8:29:40 FM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase modified INFO:
>   Additional JARs have been added sep 03, 2018 8:29:40 FM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload INFO: Reloading
>   Context with name [/3dspace] has started [SPRING]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,005 (AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) -
>   Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringMVC-servlet':
>   startup date [Mon Sep 03 08:29:25 CEST 2018]; parent: Root
>   WebApplicationContext - {} [TVC-SYSTEM]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,024 (TVCServlet.java:179) - Shutdown in
>   progress... - {} [TVC-SYSTEM]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,061 (TVCServlet.java:182) - Heippa - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,126 (AjaxJSONTransactionFilter.java:101) -
>   Destroying AjaxJSONTransactionFilter... - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,131 (Log.java:440) -
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: destroy
>   called - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,131 (AjaxJSONServiceFilter.java:62) - Destroying
>   AjaxJSONServiceFilter... - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,132 (AjaxJSONTransactionFilter.java:101) -
>   Destroying QaTransactionFilter... - {} [SPRING]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,171 (AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) -
>   Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 03 08:27:41
>   CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,175 (AbstractExecutorsConfiguration.java:116) -
>   About to destroy executor: CORE_ASYNC_JOBS - {} [CASTOR]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,175 (AbstractExecutorsConfiguration.java:116) -
>   About to destroy executor: CORE_ASYNCHRONOUSLY_WITH_DELAY - {}
>   [SPRING] [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,175 (MBeanExporter.java:449) - Unregistering
>   JMX-exposed beans on shutdown - {} [SPRING]
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO
>   2018-09-03T08:29:41,175 (MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:241) -
>   Unregistering JMX-exposed beans - {} sep 03, 2018 8:29:41 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
>   INFO: Undeploying app:
>   C:\GIT\castor\castor-main\HM_PDM\src\castor-webapp\target\castor-webapp
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info INFO:
>   Using 'openjpa.Log=org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALogFactory'
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler
>   destroyApplication WARNING: Log4j not installed. The following
>   properties will be ignored. sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM
>   org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
>   WARNING: Ignored Property overrides property 'log4j.skipJansi' sep 03,
>   2018 8:29:42 FM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler
>   destroyApplication INFO: Undeployed app:
>   C:\GIT\castor\castor-main\HM_PDM\src\castor-webapp\target\castor-webapp
>   sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/3dspace] appears
>   to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it.
>   This is very likely to create a memory leak. sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/3dspace] appears
>   to have started a thread named
>   [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser]
>   but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory
>   leak. sep 03, 2018 8:29:42 FM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesThreads

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure for TomEE, but Tomcat's algorithm is dead simple:
 Scan the webapps folder for changed files (or folders if you work with Exploded WARs, it's quite the same in terms of the asked question).

The file is considered changed if its last modification/update time changes. Another option is that a file is completely new.

When such a file is detected, it triggers the undeploy of the old version of the application and deploys a new one.

Note, this algorithm doesn't analyze the file for internal changes, its just doesn't matter, if you changed the file, then probably you wanted it to redeploy.

So the answer is simple - just don't update the webapps folder if you don't want to redeploy.